# Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Access-report-files-after-evaluation-period-expired/m-p/438594#M6100) script but receiving exception with the ExecuteReader.

> Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect
> syntax near ','."
>
> - $rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();

```
# Select-Statement for file name & blob data with filter.
#$sql = "SELECT CT.[Path]
#              ,CT.[Type]
#              ,CONVERT(varbinary(max), CT.[Content]) AS BinaryContent
#        FROM dbo.[Catalog] AS CT
#        WHERE CT.[Type] IN (2, 8, 5,11,13)";
        
# replacing with a single known PBI report that has all 3 parts in the  CatalogItemExtendedContent  
$sql = "SELECT  CT.[Path]
        ,CT.[Type]
        ,ISNULL(cc.ContentType,'SSRS') as ContentType
        ,CONVERT(varbinary(max), cc.[Content]) AS PBI_BinaryContent
        ,CONVERT(varbinary(max), ct.[Content]) AS RDL_BinaryContent
FROM dbo.[Catalog] AS CT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CatalogItemExtendedContent cc
            ON ct.ItemID = cc.ItemId
WHERE CT.[Type] IN (2, 8, 5,13)
    AND ISNULL(cc.ContentType,'CatalogItem') = 'CatalogItem'";      
 #       WHERE CT.[Type] IN (8)";

# Open ADO.NET Connection with Windows authentification.
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=True;";
$con.Open();

# New command and reader.
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $sql, $con;
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I thought maybe enclosing the connection parameters with parenthesis may do the trick, but that didnt help and still getting the exception...

```
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($sql, $con);
```

Comment: Without the value of `$sql` it's impossible for us to tell you much here. YOu have an error in your SQL; you need to fix it.

Comment: @Larnu my bad, i added the sql now

Comment: Apart from the non-SARGability of the query, due to the use of `ISNULL` on the column `cc.ContentType` in the `WHERE`, I don't see anything wrong with that SQL statement.

Comment: @Larnu right, so why si it complaining about a comma lol. thats why i thought maybe its `$sql, $con;` but even paranthesis didnt resolve it...

Comment: The error pertains to the contents of your `$sql` variable. Try adding a `Write-Host $sql` line before your `ExecuteReader` line. The `$sql` you're trying to execute almost certainly isn't what has been posted posted in the question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I didnt change anything, it's the same sql statement from the powerbi forum

Comment: I guess you'll need to ask the PowerBI forum then, because there's nothing wrong with what you've posted here.